# Where can I log & debug Velocity Template Language (VTL) in AWS AppSync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

1. Is there any easy way to log or debug VTL coming from Request Mapping Template & Response Mapping Template rather than sending **Queries** & **Mutations** to debug & log?
2. Also, is there any Playground to check & play with VTL just like we can do with JavaScript in Web Console?
3. Can we work with AWS AppSync offline & check if everything written in VTL works as expected?

Comment: 1. Thanks for bringing this up. I am on the AWS AppSync team and will follow up internally with a feature request on your behalf.
2. You can currently test your mapping templates using a mock/test data via AppSync Console.
3. Approach #2 does not involve a round trip to the DataSources and the test data is used to validate your templates.

Comment: Thanks @ShankarRaju Also, the docs aren't quite there yet. So please just make them better if you can. Here's my relevant problem https://twitter.com/deadcoder0904/status/997431929346707456

Comment: Will take your feedback to the team. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @ShankarRaju It is a junk way of introducing one more language for these templating. Why not use a widely used programming language such as nodejs, python as we are purely dealing with data objects. I never saw anyone in my 25+ years of experience who knows VTL and I don't see a need for it.

Answer (score 21):

A super nasty way to log and debug is using validate in the response mapping

```
$util.validate(false, $util.time.nowISO8601().substring(0, 10) )
```

Comment: i'll tick the answer when i work with appsync again till then have an upvote :)

Comment: It is called a half-baked product that is released to production by AWS

Comment: it is nightmare to debug AppSync VTL :-(

Comment: Why didn't I find the above two comments before I started with AppSync?...

Comment: Is it still the only/best way to log/debug VTL in AppSync?

Comment: AWS released a update for Amplify. where they got some local vtl debugging support. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/amplify-framework-local-mocking/ but still a nightmare to debug VTL in general

Comment: Awesome, thanks! VTL is nasty, but at least your solution gives us a chance to debug it.

Comment: There is a proper way now to debug it in 2020? 
has something been changed, I saw the article above where you can check for syntax error but not for proper debugging.

Hope there is any news on that.

Answer (score 17):

Here's how I logged a value in my VTL resolver:

Add a "$util.error" statement in your request or response template and then make the graphql call.

For example, I wanted to see what was the arguments passed as an input into my resolver, so I added the $util.error statement at the beginning of my template. So, my template was now:

```
$util.error("Test Error", $util.toJson($ctx))
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "PutItem",
    "key": {
        "id": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.arguments.user.id)
    },
    "attributeValues": {
        "name": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.arguments.user.name)
    }
}
```

Then from the "Queries" section of the AWS AppSync console, I ran the following mutation:

```
mutation MyMutation {
  addUser(user: {id: "002", name:"Rick Sanchez"}) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

This displayed the log results from my resolver as follows:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "addUser"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "{\"arguments\":{\"user\":{\"id\":\"002\",\"name\":\"Rick Sanchez\"}},\"identity\":null,\"source\":null,\"result\":null,\"request\":{\"headers\":{\"x-forwarded-for\":\"112.133.236.59, 130.176.75.151\",\"sec-ch-ua-mobile\":\"?0\",\"cloudfront-viewer-country\":\"IN\",\"cloudfront-is-tablet-viewer\":\"false\",\"via\":\"2.0 a691085135305af276cea0859fd6b129.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)\",\"cloudfront-forwarded-proto\":\"https\",\"origin\":\"https://console.aws.amazon.com\",\"content-length\":\"223\",\"accept-language\":\"en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8\",\"host\":\"raxua52myfaotgiqzkto2rzqdy.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\",\"x-forwarded-proto\":\"https\",\"user-agent\":\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36 Edg/87.0.664.66\",\"accept\":\"*/*\",\"cloudfront-is-mobile-viewer\":\"false\",\"cloudfront-is-smarttv-viewer\":\"false\",\"accept-encoding\":\"gzip, deflate, br\",\"referer\":\"https://console.aws.amazon.com/\",\"x-api-key\":\"api-key-has-been-edited-out\",\"content-type\":\"application/json\",\"sec-fetch-mode\":\"cors\",\"x-amz-cf-id\":\"AvTMLvtxRq9M8J8XntvkDj322SZa06Fjtyhpf_fSXd-GmHs2UeomDg==\",\"x-amzn-trace-id\":\"Root=1-5fee036a-13f9ff472ba6a1211d499b8b\",\"sec-fetch-dest\":\"empty\",\"x-amz-user-agent\":\"AWS-Console-AppSync/\",\"cloudfront-is-desktop-viewer\":\"true\",\"sec-fetch-site\":\"cross-site\",\"sec-ch-ua\":\"\\\"Chromium\\\";v=\\\"87\\\", \\\" Not;A Brand\\\";v=\\\"99\\\", \\\"Microsoft Edge\\\";v=\\\"87\\\"\",\"x-forwarded-port\":\"443\"}},\"info\":{\"fieldName\":\"addUser\",\"parentTypeName\":\"Mutation\",\"variables\":{}},\"error\":null,\"prev\":null,\"stash\":{},\"outErrors\":[]}",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 9,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Test Error"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I found this very useful, so upvote from me. I used it like this to better align it with the error object just for readibility:

`$util.error("DEBUG", 'REQUEST', null, $postBody)`

Which gives a response like this:

`"message": "DEBUG",
"errorType": "REQUEST",
"data": null,
"errorInfo": "{\"postBodyStuff\":\"whatever\"}"`

Comment: Printing the `context` and these `info` fields is helpful: `$util.error($util.toJson($context), $util.toJson($context.info.selectionSetList), null, $util.toJson($context.info.selectionSetGraphQL))`

Answer (score 10):

Looks like you are looking for this new VTL logging utility such as

`$util.log.info(Object) : Void`

Documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/utility-helpers-in-util.html

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now. Glad they added an actual logging utility - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The answers to each of your 3 questions are as follows:

1. To unit test request/response mapping templates, you could use the method described in this blog post ([https://mechanicalrock.github.io/2020/04/27/ensuring-resolvers-aren't-rejected.html](https://mechanicalrock.github.io/2020/04/27/ensuring-resolvers-aren%27t-rejected.html)).
2. A Playground for VTL experimentation exists in the AWS AppSync console where you you can edit and test the VTL for your resolvers.
3. The Amplify framework has a mock functionality which mocks AppSync, the AppSync VTL environment and DynamoDB (using DynamoDB Local). This would allow you to perform e2e tests locally.

Answer (score 1):

When I realized how much a pain it was to debug VTL, I created a lambda (nodejs) that logged the contents of my VTL template.

```js
// my nodejs based debug lambda -- very basic
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const origin = context.request || 'oops';

  if (context && context.prev) {
    console.log('--------with context----------------');
    console.log({ prev: context.prev.result, context, origin });
    console.log({ stash: context.stash });
    console.log('--------END: with context----------------');

    callback(null, context.prev.result);
  }

  console.log('inside - LOGGING_DEBUGGER');
  console.log({ event, context: context || null, origin });

  callback(null, event);
};
```

This lambda helped me debug many issues inside my pipeline resolvers. However, I forgot if I used it as a direct lambda or with request+response templates.

To use it, I put values that I wanted to debug into `$ctx.stash` in my other pipeline functions. Then in my pipeline, I added the "debugger" function after this step -- in case there was an issue where my pipeline would blow up before a fatal error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, and a lot has happened since the question was asked. I'll try to bring more up-to-date insights.

First of all, it's worth mentioning that [AppSync now supports JavaScrit resolvers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-appsync-graphql-apis-supports-javascript-resolvers/). This is a game changer when it comes to Developer Experience. I highly recommend t.

To answer the original questions:

1. Both VTL and JS resolvers now both support logging.

With JS resolvers, you can simply use `console.log()`. The logged data will show up in CloudWatch.

2. Testing resolvers is now possible.

The aws CLI comes with a command that allows you to test resolvers without having to deploy and invoke a Query. [See the doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/test-debug-resolvers-js.html)

3. As other mentioned, some solutions are available to test AppSync locally (namely, Amplify CLI). However, I would not recommend it. Instead, I prefer testing directly in the cloud. t gives more confidence that it works as expected. Unfortunately, it is still a bit of a pain (because of deployment time), but hopefully, this will improve over time thanks to features like CDK hotswap, SAM accelerate, etc.

You can also use the evaluation command to [write unit/integration tests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/test-debug-resolvers-js.html)

Additionally to all the above, which are "built-in" solutions, I created an app, [GraphBolt](http://graphbolt.dev/), that aims to improve AWS AppSync DX and tres solve some of the pain points mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `$util.log.info(Object) : Void` from [CloudWatch logging utils](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/utility-helpers-in-util.html#utility-helpers-in-util-1)

PS: you need to turn on logging to Amazon CloudWatch Logs plus setting  **Field resolver log level** on **ALL** more details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/monitoring.html).